# load external html file to div using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, load

I am using a html page which has many tooltips. each tooltip has a gallery, since it is not possible to use multiple gallery which has same id, I am planning to create 6 different html files for gallery, then load the gallery into my default page.

I need to cal the html page for each div.
I tried .load but it is not working.

```
<div id="flrmain">need to call the html file inside this div.<div>
```

Please help.

Comment: What means 'not working'? Nothing happens? You get errors? Not all content gets loaded? etc. Please post the code you tried.

Comment: No it's not working!! I have added only div portion in external html (without doctype/body/html tags)..  tried with below code but not getting html page inside my div.                 $.get('timeless_op1.html')
 .success(function(data) {
     $('#flrmain').html(data);
 });

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$.get('test.html')
 .success(function(data) {
     $('div.content').html(data);
 });
```

---

**EDIT**

If you need it for that specific `div`, replace `'div.content'` with `'#flrmain'`.

Comment: Replace `test.html` with your url (you can also specify query parameters, just check out the documentation at jquery).

Comment: `.success` is deprecated, use `.done` instead. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/