# Replace div tag with code from external file

Tags: jquery, html, file

What I want to do with jQuery is to load html code in an external html file called File.html. I want the html code to render on the page without having to push a button and the div tag to either contain the html code or to be replaced by the html code from File.html

I've tried from [Stack Overflow question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849668/load-external-html-file-to-div-using-jquery):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#File").load("Path/File.html");
        });
    </script>
    <title>BLAHBLAHBLAH</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="File"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I also tried the below from [Stack Overflow question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849668/load-external-html-file-to-div-using-jquery) :

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.get('Path/File.html')
            .success(function(data) {
            $('#File').html(data);
        });
    </script>
    <title>BLAHBLAHBLAH</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="File"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

File.html looks like:

```
<p>Worked</p>
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Try checking the developer tools console in your browser for errors.

Comment: ↑↑↑ specially the network tab. Anyway, you have to debug it on your side, no one can help you with so less info you provide as if success callback is fired or not

Comment: You have a `</head>` after your `</body>` for some reason, which should really be a `</html>`

Comment: I'm getting Blocked Loading mixed active content "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" when I checked developer tools console

Comment: Sorry, let me change to </head> to </html> that is a non issue though

Comment: I'm guessing it's a cross origin request issue.

Comment: Try changing `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com` to `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com`, assuming you're testing this on an actual server.

Comment: Are you running this on your local file system or on a server? If it's the former it will never work - requests to the local file system through JS will always be blocked for security reasons.

Comment: I'm testing on a local websphere server

Comment: Just tested your code in MAMP and it's working just fine.

Comment: I changed <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com to <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com and I am getting the same result

Comment: How does the code work APAD1? Was div tag replaced by p tag? Did you use the first example I placed in my question?

Comment: Both versions of your code work, and no, the div was not replaced, the p tag was inserted into the div since that's how you have it coded. Maybe your path is wrong.

Comment: Redeployed server and getting same issue

Comment: Use a different server, try MAMP/WAMP/LAMP

Comment: I have to use the websphere server