# Load another url into a html page using Jquery loads the same page

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to load another Url into div tag using jquery on click function. But it loads the same page into the div tag.

Below is my code:

**Jquery:**

```
function loadPage() {
    $('#xterm').load('http://google.com',function () {
        alert('Page Loaded');
    });
}
```

**HTML:**

*button:*

```
<button class="btn btn-primary Border" type="button" onclick="loadPage()">
```

*div:*

```
<div class="ScrollStyles1" id="xterm"> </div>
```

Comment: I don't think you can load an external URL using `.load()`. Look here for info on how to load external URL's: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849668/load-external-html-file-to-div-using-jquery

Comment: I tried it doesn't load external URL. Thanks for your help @Joshua Terrill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is working well but browser ignores it due to security reason. Please run your code and check console [here is the console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzgIf.png)

for this you need to do is
The URL to be loaded must either be on the same domain as the page that's calling it, or enable cross-origin HTTP requests.

You should download extension for Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* in browser to see the effects.

Comment: Both are same domain. I test both in local server only i.e: locahost. How to enable cross-origin requests

Comment: Check you console by inspect element and check error. I hope so your are getting some error.

Comment: Wow what a prediction. Yeah! you're right am getting some error in console. Thanks!!!!!